# Working on Files in Similarly (but differently) Named Directories

Tags: bash, shell

I have 2 files on which I need to run various commands.  These two files have the exact same name, but are in different folders.  The trouble is in the folder names.  I can count on these things in regards to the folders:

1)  The path leading up to the folders will always be the same.

2)  The first folder will always include one hyphen in the name.

a. Before the first hyphen will be the same across all servers.

b. After the first hyphen will be different across servers, but the same on the same server (like a servername, but not always specifically servername).

3)  The second folder will always include the same name as the first folder, but with a second hyphen along with another random set of characters.

Here's a more visual breakdown:

```
Server01
    /same/fld/path/dir1/
                    |
                    +--same-nameX/
                    |         |
                    |         +--sameFileName
                    |
                    +--same-nameX-abc123/
                              |
                              +--sameFileName

Server02
    /same/fld/path/dir1/
                    |
                    +--same-nameY/
                    |         |
                    |         +--sameFileName
                    |
                    +--same-nameY-a1b2c3/
                              |
                              +--sameFileName
```

I'm scripting in bash, and I'm trying to write a script that works regardless of the server I'm running it on.

So my question is, how can I formulate a bash command (for simplicity, "cat") such that it authoritatively works on one file vs the other?

For exampe, this:

```
cat /same/fld/path/dir1/same-*-*/sameFileName
```

This will definitely give me the contents of "same-nameX-abc123/sameFileName"

However, this:

```
cat /same/fld/path/dir1/same-*/sameFileName
```

This won't work, because it will affect both files, and I want to specifically work on the file ".../same-nameX/sameFileName".

Any help would be appreciated.

To add additional clarity, this question isn't related to folder names with a single character difference.  It's related to folders that are significantly different, but the differences lie between "hyphens".  Here are some examples:

```
Server03
    /same/fld/path/dir1/same-zxy12/sameFileName
    /same/fld/path/dir1/same-zxy12-xYz/sameFileName

Server04
    /same/fld/path/dir1/same-g1f2e3d4/sameFileName
    /same/fld/path/dir1/same-g1f2e3d4-ab12c345/sameFileName

Server05
    /same/fld/path/dir1/same-nmo/sameFileName
    /same/fld/path/dir1/same-nmo-ab/sameFileName
```

Again, thank you, everyone, anyone, for your knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using an extended glob to match the first file in each of your cases:

```
shopt -s extglob # enable extended globbing
cat /same/fld/path/dir1/same-!(*-)/sameFileName
```

This pattern will match any directory name not containing another `-`.

Comment: Testing with "cat /same/fld/path/dir1/same-!(\*-\*)/sameFileName" <-- That's working for me so far, and OMG THANK YOU!!!  For curiosity's sake though, is there a method not using "extglob"?  I NEED the script, but I'd like something I could use on the command-line, or email to others.  I've tested "cat /same/fld/path/dir1/same-[[:alnum:]]/sameFileName", but that's not working either.

Comment: There's possibly a way around it without extglob but you can always enable it in the interactive shell in the same way, so that would be my recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try use character range like this:

`cat /same/fld/path/dir1/same-name[a-zA-Z$]/sameFileName`

Comment: The way this answer is currently written makes it sounds like it should be a comment.  Can you word your answer to be more concrete or provide additional information about what your `cat` command does?

Comment: I tried your answer, but from what I understand, [a-zA-Z$] is only a test for the last character, to make sure it's alphabetic (lower case or upper case).  My needs aren't based on a single character, but rather the lack of a secondary hyphen.  I tried "cat /same/fld/path/dir1/same-[[:alnum:]]/sameFileName", but that's not doing the trick either.

Comment: @RussNS `[a-zA-Z$]` means one letter or the char `$` itself. It doesn't mean end of line as it is inside the brackets.